# Batch file rename: zero padding time with regex?

Tags: python, regex, rename, filenames

I have a whole set of files (10.000+) that include the date and time in the filename. The problem is that the date and time are not zero padded, causing problems with sorting.

The filenames are in the format: `output 5-11-2018 9h0m.xml`
What I would like is it to be in the format: `output 05-11-2018 09h00m.xml`

I've searched for different solutions, but most seem to use splitting strings and then recombining them. That seems pretty cumbersome, since in my case day, month, hour and minute then need to be seperate, padded and then recombined.

I thought regex might give me some better solution, but I can't quite figure it out.

I've edited my original code based on the suggestion of Wiktor Stribiżew that you can't use regex in the replacement and to use groups instead:

```
import os
import glob
import re

old_format = 'output [1-9]-11-2018 [1-2]?[1-9]h[0-9]m.xml'
dir = r'D:\Gebruikers\<user>\Documents\datatest\'   

old_pattern = re.compile(r'([1-9])-11-2018 ([1-2][1-9])h([0-9])m')

filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, old_format))
for file in filelist:
    print file
    newfile = re.sub(old_pattern, r'0\1-11-2018 \2h0\3m', file)
    os.rename(file, newfile)
```

But this still doesn't function completely as I would like, since it wouldn't change hours under 10. What else could I try?

Comment: You can't use a regex in the replacement, use groups in the regex and placeholders like `\1`, `\2`, etc. in the replacement to refer to those values. See `re.sub` docs.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me at least some in the right direction. This helped me formulate a re.sub that could change at least part of the filenames. But I would realy like to also find a solution that zero pads everything based on the number of digits already present (so 1 -> 01 and 12 -> 12). Do you have some more pointers?

Comment: Instead of `r'0\1-11-2018 \2h0\3m'`, use `lambda x: '{}-11-2018 {}h{}m'.format(x.group(1).zfill(2), x.group(2).zfill(2), x.group(3).zfill(2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad the numbers in your file names with `.zfill(2)` using a lambda expression passed as the replacement argument to the `re.sub` method.

Also, fix the regex pattern to allow 1 or 2 digits: `(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])` for a date, `(2[0-3]|[10]?\d)` for an hour (24h), and `([0-5]?[0-9])` for minutes:

```
old_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])-11-2018 (2[0-3]|[10]?\d)h([0-5]?[0-9])m')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lwnyar/1).

Then use:

```
for file in filelist:
    newfile = re.sub(old_pattern, lambda x: '{}-11-2018 {}h{}m'.format(x.group(1).zfill(2), x.group(2).zfill(2), x.group(3).zfill(2)), file)
    os.rename(file, newfile)
```

See Python [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) docs:

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

Comment: `old_pattern` needs to change as it requires hours have 2 digits. Either/both hours and minutes (or day/month) can be single digits and need fixing. But you need to be flexible because you don't want a date field with 2 digits to cause it not to match if other date fields only have 1 digit. A bracketed a|b expression would do the job but repeat bits of regex all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going more generic with old_pattern for simplicity, assuming your filenames are only misbehaving with digits:

Because combinations of filenames matching a single-digit field that needs converting in any position but are double digits in other fields would need a long regex to list out more explicitly, I suggest this much simpler one to match the files to rename, which makes assumptions that there are only this matching type of file in the directory as it opens it up more widely in order to be simpler to write and read at a glance - find any single digit field in the filename (one or more of) - ie. non-digit, digit, non-digit:

`old_format = r'output\.*\D\d\D.*\.xml'`

The fixing re.sub statement could then be:

`newfile = re.sub(r'\D(\d)[hm-]', lambda x: x.group()[0]+x.group()[1].zfill(2)+x.group()[2], file)`

This would also catch unicode non-ascii digits unless the appropriate re module flags are set.

If the year (2018 in example) might be given as just '18' then it would need special handling for that - could be separate case, and also adding a space into the re.sub regex pattern set (ie `[-hm ]`).

Comment: I dislike the repeated calls to .group() but its a lambda so can't save in a local function variable. Could convert to one, or maybe check if there's a more direct access. Another alternative is a mini re.sub() inside the lambda (I also think thats ugly)